# Android Database Storing & Retrieving

Tags: android, database

Hi I am a New to Android. Can Some One Describe the way if any of storing a Image to Android database & retrieve it ?

Comment: Consider yourself lucky that you don't know how to save an image into the db. IT's a very bad way of doing it. Just insert the link or file path instead.

Comment: Files or any binary data should very very rarely be stored inside of a DB. They should be stored by the file system, with the path to the file stored in the DB. Long story short, relational/SQL databases do not handle that sort of data very well at all and is considered an industry antipractice to do this not only in Android, but programming in general.

Comment: `Can Some One Describe the way` ... this is not a tutorial site,

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html)...

and you can use this code :
for storing image :

```
Map<String, byte[]> hh = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

String hi = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLjuP.jpg";
byte[] logoImagedata = getLogoImage(hi);       

hh.put("img",logoImagedata);
```

for retriving :

```
byte[] imageByteArray = hh.get("img");

ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

and getLogoImage:

```
private byte[] getLogoImage(String url){
       try {
               URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
               URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

               InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
               BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

               ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
               int current = 0;
               while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                       baf.append((byte) current);
               }

               return baf.toByteArray();
       } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
               return null;
       }

  }
```

Comment: Thank You So Much For Your Help :)

Comment: if this answer help  you and solve your problem , so accept the answer for other person .